# I can't seem to get code chunks in R to work (using LaTeX)

Tags: r, latex

Using the following R script:

```
X = 2:10

summary(X)
```

I want to output only the results of the `summary(X)` command and omit the `X = 2:10` part in my output in my LaTeX builder.

I've been trying for a few hours now using many different websites, but none of them seem to be working as intended.

Can anybody explain to me what I should include in both my R script **and** also my LaTeX input to make it work?

Comment: Have a look at rmarkdown from rstuidio.

Comment: @Christoph: It's not really an option for me to write my report in anything other than LaTeX at the moment, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

See the help page `?RweaveLatex`; you're interested in

```
<<chunkid, echo = FALSE>>=
X = 2:10
summary(X)
@
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to find a slightly different solution by using `<<chunkid, include = FALSE>>=` which did the trick. For some reason they didn't include that argument in [their manual](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Knitr).

Comment: You are using Sweave not knitr, and the manual is available at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/RweaveLatex.html

Answer (score 0):

In R Markdown, this works for me:

````
---
title: "Your latex"
author: "yourself"
date: "6/9/2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# your paper intro: 

```{r, echo = TRUE, include = TRUE}
   X = 2:10

        summary(X)
```
````

Comment: What exactly is R markdown? I'm currently using Sharelatex. Does the first part go into the R script and the second part in the Latex input?

Comment: Here there are plenty of details https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be a different platform however, and it's unfortunately not possible for me to switch to a different platform at this point.

Comment: Fair enough; this link may help: https://www.overleaf.com/help/71-how-do-i-include-sections-of-r-code-within-my-latex-document#.Wxw_gC_MxQI